# Facebook share api for android opens web-based dialog instead of native app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

I implement facebook share in my android app and as I read the docs it says :

"The Share dialog switches to the native Facebook for Android app, then returns control to your app after a post is published. Depending on the SDK you're using, people may need tap the back arrow icon to return to your app. If the Facebook app is not installed, the Share dialog automatically falls back to the web-based dialog."

I have this facebook share fucntion in `MainActivity`:

```
    fun facebookShare() {
        try {
            val content = ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Avedot"))
                .setQuote(getString(R.string.facebookText))
                .build()
            val shareDialog = ShareDialog(this)
            if (shareDialog.canShow(content)) {
                shareDialog.show(content)
            }
        } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Facebook have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

and when I call the function it opens a web-based dialog instead of the facebook app (which is installed).. I tried reinstalling but still it does not work.. any suggestions why the share dialog opens as a web-based dialog and not in the native facebook app?

this is the web-based dialog it opens:
[image]

Comment: What's your Android and Facebook app version? Can you try on a different device?

Answer (score 0):

Let check your SDK, maybe it relate to version of SDK.

> Advanced Topics

> Built-In Share Fallbacks

> In past versions of the SDK for Android, your app had to check for a native, installed Facebook app before it could open the Share Dialog. If the person didn't have the app installed, you had to provide your own code to call a fallback dialog.

> Now the SDK automatically checks for the native Facebook app. If it isn't installed, the SDK switches people to their default browser and opens the Feed Dialog.